# Any way to specify a path pattern with parameters in RestKit 0.20?

Tags: ios, restkit

I am trying to consume a web service for which the path `object?special=true&id=100` should map to a `SpecialObject` and path `object?special=false&id=100` should map to a `RegularObject`.

But when I try to use `pathPattern`s of `"object?special=true"` and `"object?special=false"` in my `RKResponseDescriptor`s it is not working - RestKit reports that the URL `object?special=true&id=100` does not match any descriptors.

Is it possible to specify a path pattern for use in `RKResponseDescriptor` that incorporates a specific parameter value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. The pattern matching is based on the path, not the parameters. I don't think it's possible to use the parameters during pattern matching.

One option is to use a dynamic mapping which looks at the URL and interprets the query parameters to decide the mapping.

Another option could be to use metadata while mapping as this gives you access to the URL and the parameters it contains.

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions. Do you happen to know if the lack of parameter-based pattern matching is by design or just a missing feature?

Comment: Parameters aren't very RESTful, though it isn't a rule. Usually required parameters are part of the URL path and optional are in the query.

Comment: @Pork'n'Bunny you probably want to create a question to detail what you're doing and what you would like it to do differently.

Comment: actually it does ignore the parameters by default. the change i made that included parameters just exposed a different problem.